# I cannot emit any messages with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a chat room, where I pass user session from passport + express to socket.io. but now I cannot emit any messages. io.on does not seem to connect.

I don't get any error messages

Here is my code

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

// Add connect-mongo to project - npm install connect-mongo
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var chatdb = require('./app/models/chat.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
// NOTE: This might need to be put into a callback/promise inside an initialize function
var db = mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating


// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Create a MongoDB storage object
var mongoStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: db.connection,
  collection: configDB.sessionCollection,
});

// Intercept Socket.io's handshake request
io.use(function (socket, next) {
  // Use the 'cookie-parser' module to parse the request cookies
  cookieParser('secret')(socket.request, {}, function (err) {
      // Get the session id from the request cookies
      var sessionId = socket.request.signedCookies ? socket.request.signedCookies['session-key'] : undefined;

      if (!sessionId) return next(new Error('sessionId was not found in socket.request'), false);

      // Use the mongoStorage instance to get the Express session information
  mongoStore.get(sessionId, function (err, session) {
      if (err) return next(err, false);
      if (!session) return next(new Error('session was not found for ' + sessionId), false);

      // Set the Socket.io session information
      socket.request.session = session;
      console.log(session);
      console.log(socket.request.user);

      // Use Passport to populate the user details
      passport.initialize()(socket.request, {}, function () {
      passport.session()(socket.request, {}, function () {
      // This will prohibit non-authenticated users from connecting to your
      // SocketIO server.
  if (socket.request.user) {
  next(null, true);
  } else {
  next(new Error('User is not authenticated'), false);
  }
    });
    });
    });
    });
});

// socket.io
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('a use connected');
    var name = "efe";
    chatdb.saveMsg({name: name, msg: msg}, function(err){
      if(err) throw err;
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('user disconnected');
});
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
http.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

This is my client side code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>chat message</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chat.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="messages"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> </div>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('.messages').append($('<div class=bubble><br/>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just so you know, `if(err) throw err;` inside an async callback is pretty much worthless error handling since the error doesn't go anywhere useful.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out all the `io.use()` so you just have a much simpler socket.io chat responder?  And, what do you observe?  Do your express routes work?  Is the server running?  Does the client successfully connect on socket.io?  Where's the relevant client socket.io code?

Comment: Thankyou for the error handling tip, javascript beginner.   it works if i comment out io.use(). all express routes are working. theserver is working and i've added the relevant client side code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've tried stepping through each line and so far i've found that my mongostore is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fix

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

// Add connect-mongo to project - npm install connect-mongo
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var chatdb = require('./app/models/chat.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
// NOTE: This might need to be put into a callback/promise inside an initialize function
var db = mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating
var mongoStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: db.connection,
});
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  clear_interval: 900,
  cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  store: mongoStore,
}));



// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));




// Intercept Socket.io's handshake request
io.use(function(socket, next) {

    // Use the 'cookie-parser' module to parse the request cookies
    cookieParser('secret')(socket.request, {}, function(err) {

        // Get the session id from the request cookies
        var sessionId = socket.request.signedCookies ? socket.request.signedCookies['connect.sid'] : undefined;

        if (!sessionId) return next(new Error('sessionId was not found in socket.request'), false);

        // Use the mongoStorage instance to get the Express session information
        mongoStore.get(sessionId, function(err, session) {
            console.log('efe');
            if (err) return next(err, false);
            if (!session) return next(new Error('session was not found for ' + sessionId), false);

            // Set the Socket.io session information
            socket.request.session = session;
            console.log(sessionId);
            console.log(socket.request.user);

            // Use Passport to populate the user details
            passport.initialize()(socket.request, {}, function() {
                passport.session()(socket.request, {}, function() {
                    // This will prohibit non-authenticated users from connecting to your
                    // SocketIO server.
                    if (socket.request.user) {
                        next(null, true);
                    } else {
                        next(new Error('User is not authenticated'), false);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
  });

// socket.io
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log('a use connected');
        var name = "efe";
        chatdb.saveMsg({
            name: name,
            msg: msg
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            io.emit('chat message', msg);
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
http.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```